# Removed python from my install, how do I get it back?

Tags: re-installation

I just typed

```
sudo apt-get remove python2.6
```

I didn't realized that this command will uninstall the whole packages from my computer. Is it possible to uninstall the ubuntu without CD. Or how can I fix this big mistake?

Comment: Related: [Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications), [I deleted package 'python3' on Ubuntu and I have lost dashboard, terminal and Unity. Help me to restore my data please](https://askubuntu.com/questions/810854/i-deleted-package-python3-on-ubuntu-and-i-have-lost-dashboard-terminal-and-un)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if I understood you correctly.

I'm guessing your Ubuntu-Installation is broken because the uninstalling of the python package also removed a lot else.

I would try to (re)install the `ubuntu-desktop`[¹](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/ubuntu-desktop) meta package.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```