# Accidentally deleted /usr/lib/python3.4

Tags: apt, python, dpkg, python3

I am on ubuntu 14.04 and I accidentally deleted python3.4

I am trying

```
apt-get install python3.4
dpkg-reconfigure -a
apt-get install -f
```

But I am seeing the following errors

```
dpkg: error processing package dh-python (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.4-minimal
 python3-minimal
 python3.4
 python3
 python3-pkg-resources
 python-chardet-whl
 python-pip-whl
 python3-chardet
 python3-colorama
 python3.4-dev
 python3-dev
 python3-distlib
 python3-six
 python3-html5lib
 python3-urllib3
 python3-requests
 python3-setuptools
 python3-pip
 python3-wheel
 dh-python
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried to completely remove python3.4 using

```
apt-get remove --purge python3.4
```

and reinstalling. but it gives me the following errors

```
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Setting up python3.4-minimal (3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3) ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
Aborted
dpkg: error processing package python3.4-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 134
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.4:
 python3.4 depends on python3.4-minimal (= 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3); however:
  Package python3.4-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3.4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.4-minimal
 python3.4
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

output for @Nodak 's answer:

```
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Setting up python3.4-minimal (3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3) ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
Aborted
dpkg: error processing package python3.4-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 134
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.4:
 python3.4 depends on python3.4-minimal (= 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3); however:
  Package python3.4-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3.4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-minimal:
 python3-minimal depends on python3.4-minimal (>= 3.4.0-0~); however:
  Package python3.4-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3:
 python3 depends on python3.4 (>= 3.4.0-0~); however:
  Package python3.4 is not configured yet.
 python3 depends on python3-minimal (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package python3-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dh-python:
 dh-python depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package dh-python (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.4-minimal
 python3.4
 python3-minimal
 python3
 dh-python
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is the output when I run `dpkg-reconfigure -a`

```
dpkg-reconfigure -a
acpid stop/waiting
acpid start/running, process 26874
avahi-daemon stop/waiting
avahi-daemon start/running, process 27149
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/man/man7/bash-builtins.7.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man7/builtins.7.gz (builtins.7.gz) in auto mode
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
cgroup-lite stop/waiting
cgroup-lite start/running
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 1: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: [general]: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 2: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: backend: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 3: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: plugin_list_autosort: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: [gnome_session]: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: backend: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 7: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: integration: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 8: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: plugin_list_autosort: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 9: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: profile: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 11: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: [general_ubuntu]: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 12: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: backend: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 13: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: integration: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 14: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: plugin_list_autosort: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 15: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: profile: not found
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install python3` and/or `sudo apt-get install python3-minimal`?

Comment: @Nodak yes, i get the same error :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work after uninstalling Python 3](http://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications-dont-work-after-uninsta)

Answer (score 0):

Try fully uninstalling python by running

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python3.4
```

This will remove all dependencys installed with python

Then install python again by running

```
sudo apt-get install python3.4
```

Hope this helped,

Zimbinskers

So try installing just python not the specific version 3.4. There may be an issue with dependencys not properly being installed. So just run

`sudo apt-get install python`

And tell me the results.

Hope this helps,

Zimbinskers

Comment: I tried that. but  it gives me some more errors. I added the details in the question

Comment: not wanting to mess with my only ubuntu box atm, but does `sudo apt-get install python` install `python2` or `python3`?

Answer (score 0):

It is a mystery.
I deleted `/usr/lib/python3.4` then I `sudo apt-get purge -f python3`

(if you try this you might want a list of your packages to re-install those packages that are Python3 dependent and subsequently removed by apt-get magic.

[Instructions how to do this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)

)

I then went to reinstall python3 `sudo apt-get install -f python3`.  It failed.

`sudo apt-get -f install` was issued and a number of packages were installed.

Reissueing `sudo apt-get install -f python3` succeeded in restoring the directory `usr/lib/python3.4` and Python 3 functionality.

I reinstalled the packages lost as collateral damage.

Comment: I tried your method.

`apt-get install -f` didnot install any packages and when i try to run `apt-get install -f python3`, I see some errors. I added that to my answer.

I also tried running `dpkg-reconfigure -a` , it resulted in some errors as well. I added them to the answer

Comment: @KiranVemuri it's a mystery.  I cannot replicate your results, nor you mine.  Sorry.

Comment: mysteries of the random bit world :)