# I accidentally deleted usr/lib/python3.4 and now I'm having some problems, how can I fix this?

Tags: command-line, unity, 15.10, unity-tweak-tool

*(This is not a duplicate of [Accidentally deleted /usr/lib/python3.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711095/accidentally-deleted-usr-lib-python3-4), the errors I get are different.)*

Today I accidentally deleted `usr/lib/python3.4`, now <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd> is not working anymore, terminal and unity-tweak-tool are not opening from the app drawer.

I get this error while I try to open unity-tweak-tool from the terminal. How can I fix this?

```
Could not find platform independent libraries 
Could not find platform dependent libraries 
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to [:]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
```

**UPDATE**
After running `sudo apt install --reinstall $(dpkg -S /usr/lib/python3.* | sed -r 's/, /\n/g; s/\: .+//')` it reinstalled some things but at the end it gave me another error: `E: Internal Error, No file name for python3.4:amd64`.
After running unity-tweak-tool I now get:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f06bc180700 (most recent call first):
(core dump created)
```

Comment: Did you actually manage to fix this? It gave me the same error.. I don't want to reinstall ubuntu if possible..

Answer (score 1):

Several Python packages keep their in there so reinstalling one might not do it. See what has files in there on your system by running:

```
dpkg -S /usr/lib/python3.4
```

That will return something slightly different for everybody but the important part is reinstalling the packages it shows.

It needs a bit of processing (removing commas, chopping off the path), but here's something that does all that and gets them reinstalled.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall $(dpkg -S /usr/lib/python3.* | sed -r 's/, /\n/g; s/\: .+//')
```

In some cases you might have to prioritise (install them first) some packages over others manually but see what you get.

Comment: I only get "python3.4: /usr/lib/python3.4"