# I accidently deleted /lib/python3.8

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, python3, tkinter

I deleted /lib/python3.8 and now I can't use gnome-terminal, apt, python3 itself and couple of other programs. I was trying to free up space with bleach-bit and manually. Then I saw a 2 folders, both python3 (python3.8 and python3.9) in /usr/lib/ directory. So I deleted the old one but it was actually linked to the default python3 (I didn't knew). Now I have python3.9 but I think python3.9 is not fully installed. I can't use apt anymore because of this:

```
user@~> sudo apt reinstall python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/47.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 321097 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/usr/bin/python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1

(...)

Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f52786bb740 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

One more thing I also did 'apt remove python3-tk' (In case it might help). I really don't wanna reinstall Ubuntu cause it would be my 7th time I do it and I don't have Ubuntu 20.04 media right now. If there is no solution possible other than reinstalling please provide me the /usr/lib/python3.8 folder. I tried solution in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762321/i-accidentally-deleted-usr-lib-python3-4-and-now-im-having-some-problems-how-c) but it gave me 4 *'errors were encountered'* packages (python3, python3-lib2to3, python3-distutils, python3-gdbm:amd64 and gnome-menus) instead of 2 (python3 and python3-tk (it was only python3 after I deleted python3-tk)). I linked /usr/bin/python to python2.7 to avoid further problems.

Comment: Don't mess with python. It is needed for the system to work.

Comment: You have discovered why we don't recommend the use of BleachBit on Ubuntu systems. Based upon your continuing chain of unwise actions ("*I linked /usr/bin/python to python2.7*"), your 7th install will be merely the latest. There will be more.