# Cannot reinstall python3 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, python3, reinstall

I think that I accidentally broke Python3 and was unable to do anything. I read somewhere that the solution was to remove python3 and reinstall it, but I got yet another problem: I was able to remove it, but not to bring it back. I tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3
```

but I keep getting the following message:

```
E: The package python3 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Which seems to be redundant given that the problem is not having python3 on the first place. Every time I try to use apt-get install I get the same error.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 on my Toshiba Satellite P75-A7200, and it was working perfectly fine for almost 2 years until I accidentally (dumbly) broke python3.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the result after `sudo apt-get install python3`? There shouldn't be any need for reinstalling

Comment: The result of that was the same:

    E: The package python3 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: I had a similar problem with python3-distupgrade and I have somehow deleted my /etc/apt/sources.list file. So I generated one with this https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ and did a sudo apt dist-upgrade

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP: Apparently deleting python3 was one of the dumbest mistakes I could have made. I couldn't reinstall it because it seems that a lot of basic functions (including installing packages) depend on python3. It even broke my GUI when I restarted my computer. Luckily I was still able to backup my data and make an almost pain-free re installation of Ubuntu 14.04 (without messing up my other partitions). I guess I got lucky.

Short answer for other unexperienced Linux users like me: Do NOT uninstall python3 or any other pre-installed programs unless you absolutely know what you're doing. Ever. Unless you're willing to waste half of your day backing up your files and re installing your Ubuntu.

Comment: This is not a real solution for the issue. I am amazed that you have accepted your own answer as the solution.

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha On the contrary, when you break something as integral to the system as python reinstalling is often the path of least resistance. Especially for inexperienced users.

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha none of the other solutions I read worked (including the one you kindly provided). I could have kept trying, but after turning off my computer the GUI was completely broken and I couldn't even open the terminal. I really needed my computer next day for school, so I decided to reinstall. I accepted my own answer as the solution because it solved the problem I had, and hopefully it will warn other inexperienced users against trying to uninstall python3. I see no harm.

Comment: Now I am convinced. Actually the the solution in you answer is not reinstalling. The key point of your answer is to say how uninstalling Python deeply damaged your system which made reinstalling the OS as the best solution for ordinary users. Yet, I wish someone come with a solution to the problem in such a way there be no need for reinstalling. Thanks for your reply to my comments