# Error while upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, dpkg

I recently tried to upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04.2 but when it is starting up all I'm getting is the terminal. Nothing else. No graphics, nothing. All I can understand is that some packages haven't got downloaded properly. I'm at a loss trying to figure out what to do. I've tried using apt-get  -f install. But some packages aren't getting configured. PLEASE HELP!  Detailed steps would be much appreciated! Some packages seem to have too many errors and dpkg cannot seem to handle it! Here is the output of -f install

```
dependency problems-leaving unconfigured

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of network-manager-pptp-gnome:

network-manager-pptp-gnome depends on network-manager-pptp (=1.1.93-ubuntu1): however:

Package network-manager-pptp is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package network-manager-pptp-gnome (--configure):

dependency problems-leaving unconfigured

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plymouth-label:

plymouth-label depends on plymouth (=0.9.2-3ubuntu13.1): however:

Package plymouth is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package plymouth-label (--configure):

dependency problems-leaving unconfigured

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo:

plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo depends on plymouth (=0.9.2-3ubuntu13.1); however:

Package plymouth is not configured yet.

plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo depends on plymouth-label (=0.9.2-3ubuntu13.1); however:

Package plymouth-label is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo (--configure):

dependency problems-leaving unconfigured

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of remmina:

remmina depends on dbus-x11; however:

Package dbus-x11 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package remmina (--configure):

dependency problems-leaving unconfigured

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of remmina-plugin-rdp:

remmina-plugin-rdp depends on remmina (=1.1.2-3ubuntu1); however:

Package remmina is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package remmina-plugin-rdp (--configure):

dependency problems-leaving unconfigured

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of remmina-plugin-vnc:

remmina-plugin-vnc depends on remmina (=1.1.2-3ubuntu1); however:

Package remmina is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package remmina-plugin-vnc (--configure):

dependency problems-leaving unconfigured

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox:

rhythmbox depends on dbus; however:

Package dbus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package rhythmbox (--configure):

dependency problems-leaving unconfigured

dpkg: too many errors, stopping

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full output from `apt-get install -f` !

Comment: I can't! I haven't got enough reputation or something like that. What do I do?

Comment: You should edit your question to show the output of that command.  Without more details, no one is going to be able to help you.

Comment: Yes you can! You always have enough reputation to [edit] your own post.

Comment: I've copied the output( whatever is visible to me!) There are more of them like this. But I've lost scrollbar( all GUI features). Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Package dbus is not configured yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202321/package-dbus-is-not-configured-yet) and [Can't upgrade/update ubuntu 18.04 as apt/dpkg error is showing up](https://askubuntu.com/q/1056780/) and [Dependency errors prevent all APT commands from running, "Package libappstream-glib8:amd64 is not configured yet"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855359/)

Comment: I did a factory reset and reinstalled that time. It's been quite sometime now.