# How to fix dpkg error code (1) while trying to install vim?

Tags: grub2, dpkg, vim

While installing `vim`, I am getting these errors:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
grub-efi-amd64
grub-efi-amd64-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am facing the same problem even while upgrading. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: [Possibly helpful](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855359/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-when-updating-installing-app)

Comment: Please show us the complete output. The summary is not detailed enough. Error Code #1 simply means "a fairly common error" like a dependency conflict or post-install script failure.