# dpkg errors when trying to install LAMP

Tags: 16.04, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, lamp

I want to install lamp in my Ubuntu 16.04. I use this website: :https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04. After installing  apache and mysql when try to install php by using the below command `sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql` I get the following results:

```
[sudo] password for pseudo:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libhttp-message-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libencode-locale-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libapache2-mod-php' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'rename' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php-common' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaprutil1' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libcgi-fast-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libwrap0' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libhttp-date-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'perl-modules-5.22' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'liblwp-mediatypes-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libfcgi-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libcgi-pm-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaio1' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libio-html-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'ssl-cert' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libperl5.22' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libapr1' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaprutil1-ldap' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libhtml-tagset-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'tcpd' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'liblua5.1-0' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libhtml-template-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libtimedate-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php-mysql' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libhtml-parser-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'liburi-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
libaio1 is already the newest version (0.3.110-2).
libapache2-mod-php is already the newest version (1:7.0+35ubuntu6).
libapr1 is already the newest version (1.5.2-3).
libaprutil1 is already the newest version (1.5.4-1build1).
libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 is already the newest version (1.5.4-1build1).
libaprutil1-ldap is already the newest version (1.5.4-1build1).
libcgi-fast-perl is already the newest version (1:2.10-1).
libcgi-pm-perl is already the newest version (4.26-1).
libencode-locale-perl is already the newest version (1.05-1).
libfcgi-perl is already the newest version (0.77-1build1).
libhtml-parser-perl is already the newest version (3.72-1).
libhtml-tagset-perl is already the newest version (3.20-2).
libhtml-template-perl is already the newest version (2.95-2).
libhttp-date-perl is already the newest version (6.02-1).
libhttp-message-perl is already the newest version (6.11-1).
libio-html-perl is already the newest version (1.001-1).
liblua5.1-0 is already the newest version (5.1.5-8ubuntu1).
liblwp-mediatypes-perl is already the newest version (6.02-1).
libperl5.22 is already the newest version (5.22.1-9).
libtimedate-perl is already the newest version (2.3000-2).
liburi-perl is already the newest version (1.71-1).
libwrap0 is already the newest version (7.6.q-25).
perl is already the newest version (5.22.1-9).
perl-modules-5.22 is already the newest version (5.22.1-9).
php-common is already the newest version (1:35ubuntu6).
php-mysql is already the newest version (1:7.0+35ubuntu6).
rename is already the newest version (0.20-4).
ssl-cert is already the newest version (1.0.37).
tcpd is already the newest version (7.6.q-25).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up php7.0-common (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-common (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-json:
php7.0-json depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-json (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-opcache:
php7.0-opcache depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-opcache (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-readline:
php7.0-readline depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-readline (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-cli:
php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.22-0ubuNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
ntu0.16.04.1); however:
Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.
php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-json; however:
Package php7.0-json is not configured yet.
php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-opcache; however:
Package php7.0-opcache is not configured yet.
php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-readline; however:
Package php7.0-readline is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-cli (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php7.0:
libapache2-mod-php7.0 depends on php7.0-cli; however:
Package php7.0-cli is not configured yet.
libapache2-mod-php7.0 depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.
libapache2-mod-php7.0 depends on php7.0-json; however:
Package php7.0-json is not configured yet.
libapache2-mod-php7.0 depends on php7.0-opcache; however:
Package php7.0-opcache is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.0 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php:
libapache2-mod-php depends on libapache2-mod-php7.0; however:
Package libapache2-mod-php7.0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-mysql:
php7.0-mysql depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-mysql (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php-mysql:
php-mysql depends on php7.0-mysql; however:
Package php7.0-mysql is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package php-mysql (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
php7.0-common
php7.0-json
php7.0-opcache
php7.0-readline
php7.0-cli
libapache2-mod-php7.0
libapache2-mod-php
php7.0-mysql
php-mysql
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I uninstall it and try to again reinstall it, but every time I got these errors. I can't understand what I should do.

Comment: What exactly did you do before this message was shown? Please provide more information and the complete input and output.

Comment: sorry for late response.the above output i will get .please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Package dbus is not configured yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202321/package-dbus-is-not-configured-yet) and [Can't upgrade/update ubuntu 18.04 as apt/dpkg error is showing up](https://askubuntu.com/q/1056780/) and [Dependency errors prevent all APT commands from running, "Package libappstream-glib8:amd64 is not configured yet"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855359/)