# recover ubuntu packages

Tags: apt, sudo, uninstall

I accidently run the autoremove command and now my chrome, terminal, my software updater and many more apps are GONE.
What should I do now and how do I install them?
Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications)

Answer (score 0):

Find out which packages were removed by `sudo apt autoremove` with the help of the logfiles `/var/log/apt/history*`:

```
cd /var/log/apt
zgrep autoremove history.log*
```

Output should be similar to

```
history.log.3.gz:Commandline: apt autoremove
history.log.5.gz:Commandline: apt autoremove
history.log.5.gz:Commandline: apt autoremove
history.log.6.gz:Commandline: apt autoremove
history.log.6.gz:Commandline: apt autoremove
history.log.8.gz:Commandline: apt autoremove
```

This means the file `history.log.8.gz` (and the others) contains details about the `apt autoremove` command. Now do

```
zless history.log.8.gz
```

Find the "offending" section; type `/autoremove` to search for it or simply hit <kbd>PgDn</kbd> a few times until you find it. The logfile won't be that large. You should find a section similar to this one:

```
Start-Date: 2018-06-08  21:34:40
Commandline: apt autoremove
Requested-By: pduck (1001)
Remove: linux-image-4.13.0-39-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-39.44), linux-signed-image-4.13.0-39-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-39.44), linux-signed-image-4.13.0-38-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-38.43), linux-image-extra-4.13.0-38-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-38.43), linux-image-extra-4.13.0-39-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-39.44), libisns0:amd64 (0.97-2), linux-headers-4.13.0-38:amd64 (4.13.0-38.43), linux-headers-4.13.0-39:amd64 (4.13.0-39.44), linux-headers-4.13.0-39-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-39.44), linux-headers-4.13.0-38-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-38.43), linux-image-4.13.0-38-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-38.43)
End-Date: 2018-06-08  21:35:08
```

This means user `pduck` issued `apt autoremove` at `2018-06-08  21:34:40` and the listed packages were removed. The command completed at `2018-06-08  21:35:08`. Note that this example doesn't show an "offending" process, it's just for illustration. You need to find the `autoremove` command in your logfiles that removed the packages you are talking about.

You can also issue

```
zgrep -A2 autoremove history.log*
```

to include two lines after the matching line (`autoremove`), i.e. also show the `Remove:...` lines. Maybe that's easier for identifying the "offending" section.

Now that you have a list of removed packages you can reinstall them via `apt install`.