# Recovering the Ubuntu 19.04 after removing Python3 accidentally

Tags: networking, python3, 19.04

I accidentally removed python3 from Ubuntu 19.04, and after restarting the PC, it only displays a terminal with a disabled network, so I can't do `sudo apt-get update` or install anything.

How can I enable the network and then install python3 and recover the Ubuntu?

Comment: Download the packages with another computer from ubuntu.pkgs.org and install them via `apt deb path/to/file`

Comment: Enabling the network from shell seems a separate question (use the Search box - it's been answered several times already) from reinstalling Python3 (which has also already been asked and answered several times). For most users, it may be easier and faster to simply backup your data and reinstall - Python3 is a critical component of apt, and apt won't work without Py3. dpkg will work, but that means restoring each dependency in the proper order which may be tedious. We can give you better advice if you list the packages that were removed - it's in your /var/log/apt/history.log

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications)