# How to fix black screen on startup

Tags: command-line, screen, startup, tty

So I was trying to uninstall Python 3.8.2 and I used a command from someone that was like `sudo apt purge python3.8`

And it started uninstalling everything else, even Firefox and all, the console is gone, everything is gone. So I try to restart and now I get prompted with a lot of beautiful black pixels but nothing else.

I read something about the tty console so now I'm the tty console but nothing happens when I do `crtl + alt + F7`.

What do I do ? I'm completely lost I started using Ubuntu this morning...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) -- Python is an essential part of a TON of applications. `apt` would have notified you of the other packages this would remove -- you were not wise to accept. Also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications -- If you are new to Ubuntu - your best path is probably to reinstall the OS

Comment: OK I'll reinstall all the system... Can I use the same iso file and USB or is it signed or locked or something ?

Comment: You can use the .ISO a trillion times.  It's an image.  Same goes with the ISO flashed to the USB as long as you aren't making changes to it.