# Many apps including terminal dissapeared after installing an app

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, mbr, grub-legacy

### [Edit] THE ANSWER:

**It was my mistake I accidently unistalled python and that's why all the apps that used python (Almost all) were gone, no solution on the internet worked so finally I had to reinstall it**

I was installing python3 on my ubuntu 20.04 (dual-booted with windows 10) when I was installing it suddenly something happened and the terminal closed and disappeared from the favourites then I looked into All Apps section, I saw that many apps (I think they were the default apps) including the Terminal disappeared  then I thought a reboot would work so I did it and when it was booting I saw some errors

```
ACPI BIOS Error (BUG) : Can not resolve symbol [SOME SORT OF CODE]
```

☝ This was written multiple times and at the end of these, Something like this was written:

```
dev/sda5/something/something...
```

I don't know what it was written because it showed just for around 5-6 seconds
After this ubuntu booted and showed a popup and its title was: "Sorry, Ubuntu 20.04 has experienced an internal error"

It was happening in every boot. So, I removed ubuntu from dual boot I removed it's partition and GRUB (I am a bit unsure about the GRUB but it does not shows up on boot so I think it is removed)

And now I want to install Linux again (This time Pop OS) can anyone tell why that happened and what is the solution and how can I prevent it from happening again.

I hope I will get the Answer.
Thanks.

Some Information:

- I am using a HDD
- I have a Legacy BIOS
- My PC uses MBR
- dev/sda5 is my root.
- I didn't added any home folder Linux managed that with the root partition.
- I added a different 10GB partition for Linux swap.
- I installed the GRUB bootloader in the dev/sda5 partition instead of the actual hard disk (dev/sda).
- I used EasyBCD to boot from dev/sda5 because it will boot from the windows boot manager because as I said I didn't installed it on the whole hard disk.

Comment: I see nothing useful there. Not surprising, since you did not describe a boot-related problem. Boot-repair is a limited (partition/bootloader) tool.

Comment: I'm not sure why you were installing python3 -- it's already installed and is an integral part of Ubuntu.

Comment: Voting to close: The change from "*suddenly something happened*" to "*I broke my system by uninstalling Python*" means that the question as written is confusing, irrelevant to the actual problem, and seems unhelpful to future readera.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications)

Comment: No bro I tried that but it didn't worked I finally reinstalled linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake I accidently unistalled python and that's why all the apps that used python (Almost all) were gone, no solution on the internet worked so finally I had to reinstall it