# Ubuntu login screen stuck

Tags: command-line, python

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS **5.8.0-50-generic** I have the same problem as in this question [Removed python 3 and now Ubuntu software centre and terminal does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications). I had run a command `sudo apt-get remove python3*`. The only difference is that I had no idea that these would happen and I had shut down my computer. Now when I am trying to turn it on either the screen is stuck in the login window or the keyboard seem to not work as soon as I get into the login window. There is no way I am able to get the terminal as said in the answer of the question I have linked. The only command line I have access to now is the grub command line. I am not even sure if it is because of the loss of those dependencies or it's a driver issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hi***

Please enter in "advanced Ubuntu options" in grub and run Ubuntu with older Generic maybe this can help you to open the Ubuntu (or Kubuntu)

If it doesn't work you can enter in "advanced Ubuntu options" and go to last Generic, recovery mode and install the removed package again (from root option) or run "dpkg" and maybe your problem fixed **:*****)***

Comment: Ubuntu with older generic had the same problem. But I could install the necessary packages from root in recovery mode. Also for any command to run on root I had to enable networking from the same menu or else the system wouldn't be connected to the internet

Comment: So your problem is fixed now??

Comment: ohh yes it is fixed