# /dev/nvme0n1p8: clean ... after purge python3.8-minimal

Tags: boot, python

I executed the command

```
sudo apt purge python3.8-minimal
```

in Ubuntu. After that, the problem

> /dev/nvme0n1p8: clean ...

occurs when I start my Ubuntu.
How can I revert this?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? `/dev/nvme0n1p8: clean` isn't a problem at all.

Comment: The system simply does not start and this message appears, I suspect it is a problem related to GDM (Graphical Display Manager), after some research I saw that uninstalling Python could cause this problem...

Comment: Can you login to a TTY?

Comment: I am afraid there is no way to recover, and you'll need to reinstall. Removing `python3.8-minimal` also removes many other packages.

Comment: If you remove python; you lose access to every tool/feature of the OS that needed it to operate.  It's not wise to remove necessary tools required by your OS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications)

Comment: Why did you ever think of removing a part of base system installation?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try the recovery mode at the GRUB menu, and if it works, reinstall the removed packages.

Removing `python3.8-minimal` also removes a bunch of other packages, but I don't know if apt will work:

> sudo apt-get purge -s python3.8-minimal
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
> apport-symptoms aptdaemon-data bluez-obexd dc dconf-cli diffstat distro-info distro-info-data docbook-xml enchant ffmpeg gettext
> gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-bamf-3 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0
> gir1.2-keybinder-3.0 gir1.2-matedesktop-2.0 gir1.2-matepanelapplet-4.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0
> gir1.2-pluma-1.0 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gir1.2-secret-1 gir1.2-snapd-1 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-vte-2.91 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0
> gir1.2-wnck-3.0 intltool-debian ippusbxd libapt-pkg-perl libarchive-zip-perl libasync-mergepoint-perl libavahi-glib1 libavdevice58
> libavresample4 libb-hooks-endofscope-perl libb-hooks-op-check-perl libcapture-tiny-perl libcdio-paranoia2
> libclass-method-modifiers-perl libclass-xsaccessor-perl libclone-perl libcpanel-json-xs-perl libcroco3 libdc1394-22
> libdevel-callchecker-perl libdevel-size-perl libdigest-bubblebabble-perl libdynaloader-functions-perl libemail-valid-perl
> libenchant1c2a libexporter-tiny-perl libfile-find-rule-perl libfont-ttf-perl libfuture-perl libglu1-mesa libgtk2-perl
> libimagequant0 libimport-into-perl libio-async-loop-epoll-perl libio-async-perl libio-pty-perl libio-string-perl libipc-run-perl
> libjson-maybexs-perl libkeybinder-3.0-0 libldb2 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblinux-epoll-perl liblist-compare-perl
> liblist-moreutils-perl liblua5.2-0 libmodule-implementation-perl libmodule-runtime-perl libmoo-perl libmoox-aliases-perl
> libnamespace-clean-perl libnet-dns-perl libnet-dns-sec-perl libnet-domain-tld-perl libnet-ip-perl libnetplan0 libnfs13
> libnumber-compare-perl libopenal-data libopenal1 libpackage-stash-perl libpackage-stash-xs-perl libpango-perl
> libparams-classify-perl libpath-tiny-perl libperl4-corelibs-perl libperlio-gzip-perl libportaudio2 libpython3-stdlib
> libreadonly-perl libref-util-perl libref-util-xs-perl librole-tiny-perl libsereal-decoder-perl libsereal-encoder-perl
> libsereal-perl libstrictures-perl libstruct-dumb-perl libsub-exporter-progressive-perl libsub-identify-perl libsub-quote-perl
> libtalloc2 libtest-fatal-perl libtest-refcount-perl libtevent0 libtext-glob-perl libtext-levenshtein-perl libtype-tiny-perl
> libtype-tiny-xs-perl libunicode-utf8-perl libvariable-magic-perl libwbclient0 libxatracker2 libxcb-ewmh2 libxcb-xrm0 libxfont2
> libxml-writer-perl libxvmc1 libyaml-libyaml-perl libyelp0 lintian mscompress patchutils python-apt-common rofi rtmpdump
> samba-common sgml-base sgml-data t1utils x11-apps x11-session-utils xfonts-base xfonts-encodings xfonts-scalable xfonts-utils xinit
> xinput xml-core xserver-common xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-libinput xserver-xorg-input-wacom
> xserver-xorg-legacy xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
> xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa
> xserver-xorg-video-vmware xul-ext-ubufox yelp-xsl

Comment: Apt won't work initially. The `python3.x-minimal` package must be reinstalled using dpkg, then apt will usually work. Folks who have never used dpkg may find a complete reinstall faster and easier.