# How can I restore Ubuntu Terminal and many other software after removing python?

Tags: apt, 20.04

So, I was trying to uninstall python from my ubuntu 20.04 So, I typed the following command

```
sudo apt-get remove python3
```

and it deleted Terminal and much other software. How can undo this?

Comment: Many tools of Ubuntu require python3 to be installed; so if you remove them - those packages (eg. GUI terminal) will cannot run (as it requires or *depends* on python3 being installed).  You can still use text terminals, but you'll find many things no longer work.  (you may not be able to use `apt` & user front-end tools; but `dpkg` & basic tools will still function).  Restoration of backups, or re-install (*without format*) work too.

Comment: Is the problem solved ?

Answer (score 1):

## Best and recommended way is to backup /home and reinstall latest version of ubuntu or LTS release

## If you wana try some things

This issue is [already solved here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications) (Exactly [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/384041/1460940) )

As the answers state

First open a tty

`ctrl + alt + f5`

Login with your sudo account

Then run the following commands

```
sudo apt install *python3-all*
# downloads all python 3 things again 

sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^
# Downloads all the *default* softwares back

sudo apt-get update
# update

sudo apt-get upgrade
# upgrade

sudo apt install gnome-terminal
# Get the default gui terminal back

sudo apt install gnome-software
# Get the software app back
```