# Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine is not switching to GUI mode

Tags: vmware

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 on Vmware virtual machine and it was working fine.

By mistake, I have executed the below command.

```
sudo apt purge python3.8
```

After that, I observed weird behavior on Virtual ubuntu So, I restarted the VM. From this point, Vm is not able to switch to GUI mode it always sticks to the TTY terminal.
I can create the new VM but I setup the lots of things on that.

Please let me know the solution to my problem as soon as possible.

Comment: Ubuntu depends on the system installation of python, so you should never mess with that. All sorts of stuff will break without it, but you didn't say anything about whether you've tried to re-install python3.8, so, have you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications)

Answer (score 8):

A lot of system components got removed when you removed python. **Never** mess up with the default version of python in Ubuntu.

First, re-install python.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3
```

Then, reinstall the necessary packages for GUI.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Finally, reboot the computer with the command `sudo reboot`, and you should be greeted with the GUI.

Comment: fwiw they can probably use `ubuntu-desktop-minimal` for a VM