# GUI not appeared in virtualbox ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, gui

I created a virtual Ubuntu machine in Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager. Previously, I could access the GUI. I could navigate to folders using the mouse pointer. But now I only receive a terminal. How to set it again?

[Only terminal appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRDz9.png)

`startx` gives me nothing.

`systemctl get-default` gives me **graphical.target**

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Check if the GUI is installed first or you can re-install it with the above command.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is we should not remove default python version installed with the ubuntu installation. If so, there may be errors. Please refer to the link attached.

[Can I remove some python versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388091/can-i-remove-some-python-versions)