# Getting errors with apt update

Tags: apt, python

When I do `apt update` I get:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 12, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

all I did was https://cloudbytes.dev/snippets/upgrade-python-to-latest-version-on-ubuntu-linux, how can I fix this?

Comment: At the end of that article, there is a section titled "[OPTIONAL] Fix Python3-apt". I suggest you read that. Disclaimer: I don't know if that will work, and it may make it worse if it doesn't fix it. Moreover, messing with Python versions in Ubuntu tends to break stuff. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications) for one other example of this. Side note: We probobly need a canonical question for "I messed with Python and broke my system".

Comment: Ask https://cloudbytes.dev/snippets/upgrade-python-to-latest-version-on-ubuntu-linux They might have a clue. You have followed somebody else's `root` path, without understanding. This is a Well Known Bad Idea.

Comment: That's shite. I need python3.10 for some specific functions...what do?

Comment: Oh well, I guess it's time for `timeshift --restore` to shine...

Comment: Use Docker. Or a virtual Python environment. And keep backups, too.