# Ubuntu 22.04 how to remove Python 3.10 and 3.11

Tags: python

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 21.10 to Ubuntu 22.04. Everything perfect except for python.  Python 3.11 or 3.10 broke my python scripts. In my struggle I think i damaged the system and now I have mess: I seem to have all 3.9, 3.10, 3.11 and cannot open a terminal etc...
Can you please help?
Many thanks for reading. Best regards,
Zuheyr

Comment: If you "damaged the system", then reinstall Ubuntu to undo the damage. DON'T change the version of Python3 included with Ubuntu -- that will break your system. To run a different version of Python is fairly easy to do if you avoid the mistake of trying to install it through apt.

Comment: tried apt related command - `apt autoremove'?
Also try doing a update one more time as in `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt autoremove'
So system automatically update, upgrade & remove all packages as needed

Comment: Also, as you mentioned 'I think i damaged the system', Check your terminal command run & apt history -As it has all the history of previous runs, Its easy to find out where exactly you broke it (f you could find that, can easily revert)

Comment: Please reinstall. Messing with the default python is a fatal mistake. Almost the whole desktop  is driven by python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications)

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

and you will get your system back.

I have the same issue, I cannot install Python 3.6. Ubuntu 2022 comes with Python 3.10.

Answer (score 0):

If you have scripts that require an older version of Python and/or certain versions for specific modules and there are no packages to remedy this, your best bet—at least as a temporary workaround—is to ensure that said scripts work in a separate environment. One possible building block which I use myself is [pyenv (Simple Python version management)](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).