# Kubuntu bootloop After removing python

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, lts

I'm asking you guys for help because right now I'm desperate.

In the afternoon I accidentally removed the folder of the python version currently set as default.
On reboot the pc went into boot loop not starting the operating system and stopping in showing " ASUS "

*I also tried using a live USB and disabling fast boot but nothing at all*

I use an Asus vivobook laptop with an HDD (detail that I think may be relevant).
I ask you for help,I don't know how to solve

---

News
I've flashed and USB live and booted the pc with It.
But It still goes in bootloop

Edit: the old USB was corrupted,i tryied with a Kingston 3.0 and It worked

Comment: Even using a live USB the pc doesnt boot.

Comment: If you are SURE that is true, then removing Python was not the cause of your failure to boot. Your  motherboard has a fault. Ubuntu cannot fix broken/defective/faulty hardware.

Comment: How can i find the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications)