# Terminal is not working

Tags: command-line

I'm a student learning about Ubuntu. I have a question, but the terminal won't open. I can't open it no matter what I try, but I don't know what the problem is.
The method of the site I referred to is this. What the hell is wrong with you?
help me please. TOT
thank you.
https://www.groovypost.com/howto/cant-open-terminal-in-ubuntu-fixes/

Comment: What happens when you try to open the terminal with the Ctrl+Alt+T default keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Nothing is done... I've even changed the language, but it doesn't work

Comment: hey .. Is it possible that Python won't open unless it's the latest version? Then, what is the current version?

Comment: Yes, it happens all the time. [Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/q/384033/)

Comment: Don't ever change the default python version. Instead, use Anaconda/Miniconda to set u a virtual environment. In case you are unable to change the python version back using the link karel posted, you will have to reinstall Ubuntu

Comment: I have Python 3.10.11 version. There are 3.10.12 version and 3.11.4 version on Python homepage, so it's better to go with 3.10 version, right?

Comment: 3.10.11 and 3.11.4 were released in June this year, but were also used in June. If it is not a Python issue, no administrator is specified at this time. Do I need to assign an administrator?