# apt-get -f install suggests removing python2.7 and installing python3

Tags: apt, package-management, python, mysql, python3

Since I have some dependencies problems (I am trying to install `mysql-workbench` in a Ubuntu 12.04), I tried to run `sudo apt-get -f install`. However, the output looks very scary, since it suggests removing python2.7 and installing python3 instead (among other things).

Why does python2.7 bother him? Is it safe to accept all these removals?

Here is the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libopenal1:i386 libboost-thread1.46-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386 melt libkrb5-3:i386 libgconf-2-4:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libstdc++5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libxfixes3:i386
  libmono-sqlite4.0-cil libqt4-declarative:i386 libboost-filesystem1.46.1 libtorque2 libgstrtspserver-0.10-0 libxcomposite1:i386 libgail18:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libao-common libv4l-0:i386 liblcms1:i386
  libqt4-qt3support:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386 libunistring0:i386 libcupsimage2:i386 libgphoto2-port0:i386 libidn11:i386 libboost-regex1.46-dev librbd1 libnss3:i386 libmono-corlib4.0-cil libwrap0:i386
  libcaca0:i386 gtk2-engines:i386 libgudev-1.0-0:i386 libsamplerate0:i386 libmono-system-security4.0-cil libboost-program-options1.46-dev libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libcdparanoia0:i386 libcairo-gobject2:i386
  libavc1394-0:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libmono-cairo4.0-cil libboost-graph-parallel1.46-dev libmlt++3 libboost-graph-parallel1.46.1 libmono-system-xml4.0-cil libdrm-radeon1:i386 libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil
  libdbus-1-3:i386 msr-tools libaio1 libaio1:i386 libsane:i386 odbcinst1debian2:i386 libqt4-test:i386 libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-designer:i386 libboost-graph1.46-dev libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil seabios
  libsdl-mixer1.2:i386 cli-common libmono-system-transactions4.0-cil libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libcap2:i386 libproxy1:i386 ibus-gtk:i386 libboost-system1.46.1
  libboost-date-time-dev libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libtdb1:i386 libmono-posix4.0-cil libxcb-glx0:i386 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libboost-python1.46.1
  libboost-mpi1.46-dev libgoocanvas3 libboost-signals1.46.1 libboost-signals-dev libspeex1:i386 gvfs-libs:i386 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libgomp1:i386 libboost-program-options1.46.1
  libmono-system-core4.0-cil libcapi20-3:i386 libibus-1.0-0:i386 libcairo2:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil libgnutls26:i386 libboost-date-time1.46.1 libboost-thread-dev
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 mono-runtime libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libcanberra0:i386 librados2 libboost-test1.46.1 libtasn1-3:i386 libfreetype6:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libopenmpi-dev
  libwavpack1:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386 libsoup-gnome2.4-1:i386 libboost-program-options-dev libglib2.0-0:i386 libmysqlclient18:i386 libexpat1:i386 libv4lconvert0:i386 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386
  libboost-wave1.46.1 cpu-checker libboost-test-dev libboost-wave-dev libboost-graph1.46.1 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 librsvg2-common:i386 libdatrie1:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386
  libmono-system-data4.0-cil libiec61883-0:i386 libjson0:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libboost-graph-parallel-dev recordmydesktop libsdl-image1.2:i386 libxcb1:i386 libboost-date-time1.46-dev
  libboost-serialization-dev libboost-system-dev libp11-kit0:i386 blt libdrm2:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libxau6:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libsdl1.2debian:i386 libxaw7:i386
  libmono-system-enterpriseservices4.0-cil libgdbm3:i386 libcups2:i386 openshot-doc libcurl3:i386 libboost1.46-dev libqtcore4:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libgoocanvas-common mono-4.0-gac libesd0:i386
  libmikmod2:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 libboost-regex-dev libxft2:i386 vgabios libopenmpi1.3 mono-gac libcroco3:i386 libdrm-nouveau1a:i386 libpulse-mainloop-glib0:i386 libboost-iostreams1.46-dev
  libboost-math-dev libtheora0:i386 libice6:i386 libaa1:i386 libspeexdsp1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libgcrypt11:i386 libthai0:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libxml2:i386 libglib2.0-cil libao4:i386
  libkeyutils1:i386 libxmu6:i386 libcanberra-gtk0:i386 libvorbisfile3:i386 libqt4-sql:i386 libboost-thread1.46.1 libasound2:i386 libxpm4:i386 libflac8:i386 libqt4-svg:i386 libusb-0.1-4:i386
  libgail-common:i386 libxrender1:i386 libboost-math1.46-dev libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libraw1394-11:i386 libnspr4:i386 libshout3:i386 libdv4:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386
  libvorbisenc2:i386 librpmbuild2 libqt4-xml:i386 libasyncns0:i386 gstreamer0.10-x:i386 libgettextpo0:i386 libxss1:i386 libgd2-xpm:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libnuma1 libtiff4:i386
  libboost-signals1.46-dev libsdl-net1.2:i386 libjasper1:i386 libvisual-0.4-plugins:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 gccxml libboost-mpi-dev libboost-mpi1.46.1 libudev0:i386
  libibverbs1 libgnome-keyring0:i386 libxtst6:i386 gtk2-engines-pixbuf gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 libboost-system1.46-dev kvm-ipxe libqtgui4:i386 libtag1c2a:i386 librsvg2-2:i386 libavahi-client3:i386
  libboost-filesystem-dev libssl0.9.8:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libmad0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 qemu-utils libgnome-keyring1.0-cil gtk2-engines-oxygen:i386 libgtksourceview2.0-0
  libfontconfig1:i386 libibverbs-dev xaw3dg:i386 libboost-serialization1.46-dev libpango1.0-0:i386 libsm6:i386 libmono-i18n4.0-cil libpulse0:i386 libicu-dev libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 librpmsign0
  libboost-wave1.46-dev libpulsedsp:i386 libxdamage1:i386 gvfs:i386 libboost-dev libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 libxcb-render0:i386 libodbc1:i386 libboost-math1.46.1 libexif12:i386 libqt4-scripttools:i386
  libglu1-mesa:i386 bridge-utils librtmp0:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libxi6:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libgtk2.0-cil libqtwebkit4:i386 libmlt-data gnome-dvb-daemon libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 libxp6:i386
  libaudio2:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 mpi-default-dev libxt6:i386 libxv1:i386 libmono-data-tds4.0-cil libxext6:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libboost-iostreams-dev libavahi-common3:i386
  libboost-mpi-python-dev libboost-regex1.46.1 libxrandr2:i386 openmpi-common libboost-filesystem1.46-dev gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:i386 libboost-test1.46-dev libsndfile1:i386 libmono-security4.0-cil
  libsqlite3-0:i386 libmng1:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libboost-graph-dev libmlt4 libgdiplus libltdl7:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 glib-networking:i386
  libgpg-error0:i386 libllvm3.0:i386 libsoup2.4-1:i386 libgphoto2-2:i386 libogg0:i386 libgtksourceview2.0-common qemu-common libtag1-vanilla:i386 libmono-system4.0-cil libaudiofile1:i386
  libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a:i386 libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:i386 libglibmm-2.4-1c2a:i386 libatkmm-1.6-1:i386 libpangomm-1.4-1:i386 libcairomm-1.0-1:i386 libzip2:i386 libctemplate0:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libatkmm-1.6-1:i386 libcairomm-1.0-1:i386 libctemplate0:i386 libglibmm-2.4-1c2a:i386 libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a:i386 libpangomm-1.4-1:i386 libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:i386 libzip2:i386 python3 python3-minimal python3.2
  python3.2-minimal
Suggested packages:
  python3-doc python3-tk python3.2-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  activity-log-manager-control-center aisleriot alacarte apparmor apparmor-utils apport apport-gtk apt-xapian-index aptdaemon apturl apturl-common bluez bluez-alsa bluez-alsa:i386 bluez-gstreamer cdbs
  checkbox checkbox-qt command-not-found compiz compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-main-default compizconfig-backend-gconf d-feet dconf deja-dup diffuse duplicity eog evolution-data-server firefox
  firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support flashplugin-installer foomatic-db-compressed-ppds gaphor gconf2 gdb gdebi-core gedit gimp gir1.2-mutter-3.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0
  gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 gksu gnome-applets gnome-applets-data gnome-bluetooth gnome-contacts gnome-control-center gnome-dvb-client gnome-media gnome-menus gnome-orca gnome-panel gnome-panel-data
  gnome-rdp gnome-session-fallback gnome-shell gnome-sudoku gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnome-themes-standard gnome-user-share gstreamer0.10-gconf gtk-recordmydesktop gwibber gwibber-service
  gwibber-service-facebook gwibber-service-identica gwibber-service-twitter hplip hplip-data ia32-libs ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 ibus ibus-pinyin ibus-table indicator-datetime indicator-power
  jockey-common jockey-gtk landscape-client-ui-install language-selector-common language-selector-gnome launchpad-integration libbonoboui2-0 libboost-all-dev libboost-python-dev libboost-python1.46-dev
  libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcompizconfig0 libfolks-eds25 libgksu2-0 libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common
  libgnomeui-0 libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgweather-3-0 libgweather-common libgwibber-gtk2 libgwibber2 libmetacity-private0 libmutter0 libpeas-1.0-0 libpurple-bin libpython2.7
  libreoffice-emailmerge libreoffice-gnome librhythmbox-core5 libsyncdaemon-1.0-1 libtotem0 libubuntuoneui-3.0-1 light-themes lsb-release meld mendeleydesktop metacity metacity-common mutter-common
  mysql-workbench-gpl:i386 nautilus-share nvidia-common onboard oneconf openprinting-ppds openshot osc pidgin pidgin-libnotify printer-driver-foo2zjs printer-driver-postscript-hp printer-driver-ptouch
  printer-driver-pxljr printer-driver-sag-gdi printer-driver-splix python python-appindicator python-apport python-apt python-apt-common python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
  python-aptdaemon.pkcompat python-brlapi python-cairo python-chardet python-configglue python-crypto python-cups python-cupshelpers python-dateutil python-dbus python-debian python-debtagshw
  python-decorator python-defer python-dev python-dirspec python-egenix-mxdatetime python-egenix-mxtools python-gaphas python-gconf python-gdbm python-gi python-gi-cairo python-glade2 python-gmenu
  python-gnome2 python-gnomekeyring python-gnupginterface python-gobject python-gobject-2 python-gst0.10 python-gtk2 python-gtksourceview2 python-httplib2 python-ibus python-imaging python-keybinder
  python-keyring python-launchpadlib python-lazr.restfulclient python-lazr.uri python-ldap python-libproxy python-libxml2 python-lockfile python-louis python-m2crypto python-mako python-markupsafe
  python-memcache python-minimal python-mlt3 python-mysqldb python-notify python-oauth python-openssl python-packagekit python-pam python-pexpect python-pip python-piston-mini-client python-pkg-resources
  python-problem-report python-protobuf python-pyatspi2 python-pycurl python-pygoocanvas python-pyinotify python-pyorbit python-renderpm python-reportlab python-reportlab-accel python-rpm python-scour
  python-serial python-setuptools python-simplegeneric python-simplejson python-smbc python-software-properties python-speechd python-subversion python-support python-tk python-twisted-bin
  python-twisted-core python-twisted-names python-twisted-web python-ubuntu-sso-client python-ubuntuone-client python-ubuntuone-control-panel python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol python-uno python-urlgrabber
  python-virtkey python-virtualenv python-vte python-wadllib python-wicd python-wnck python-xapian python-xdg python-xkit python-zeitgeist python-zope.component python-zope.event python-zope.hookable
  python-zope.interface python2.7 python2.7-dev python2.7-minimal qemu-kvm qtemu r-base-dev rhythmbox rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist
  rhythmbox-plugins rhythmbox-ubuntuone sessioninstaller software-center software-center-aptdaemon-plugins software-properties-common software-properties-gtk soundconverter stgit
  system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-gnome system-config-printer-udev terminator totem totem-mozilla totem-plugins ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-sso-client
  ubuntu-sso-client-gtk ubuntu-standard ubuntu-system-service ubuntuone-client ubuntuone-client-gnome ubuntuone-control-panel ubuntuone-couch ubuntuone-installer ufw unattended-upgrades unity unity-2d
  unity-common unity-lens-applications unity-lens-video unity-scope-musicstores unity-scope-video-remote update-manager update-manager-core update-notifier update-notifier-common usb-creator-common
  usb-creator-gtk vim vim-gnome wicd wicd-daemon wicd-gtk xdiagnose xul-ext-ubufox zeitgeist zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libatkmm-1.6-1:i386 libcairomm-1.0-1:i386 libctemplate0:i386 libglibmm-2.4-1c2a:i386 libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a:i386 libpangomm-1.4-1:i386 libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:i386 libzip2:i386 python3 python3-minimal python3.2
  python3.2-minimal
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  python-minimal python2.7-minimal (due to python-minimal)
0 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 322 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 6,351 kB of archives.
After this operation, 635 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
```

**Edit:**

My (current) sources.list:

```
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe 
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe 

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe multiverse restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe multiverse restricted #Added by software-properties
```

**Edit**

sudo apt-get remove mysql-workbench*

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mysql-workbench' for regex 'mysql-workbench*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-workbench-data' for regex 'mysql-workbench*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-workbench-oss' for regex 'mysql-workbench*'
Package mysql-workbench is not installed, so not removed
Package mysql-workbench-data is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-workbench-gpl:i386 : Depends: libatkmm-1.6-1:i386 (>= 2.22.1) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libctemplate0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libglibmm-2.4-1c2a:i386 (>= 2.32.0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a:i386 (>= 1:2.24.0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: liblua5.1-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libpangomm-1.4-1:i386 (>= 2.27.1) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libpython2.7:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:i386 (>= 2.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libzip2:i386 (>= 0.10) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: python-paramiko:i386 but it is not installable
                            Depends: python-pexpect:i386 but it is not installable
                            Depends: mysql-client:i386
                            Depends: python-pysqlite2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status

```
...
MySQL Workbench 

Package: mysql-workbench-gpl
Status: install ok unpacked
Priority: extra
Section: utils
Installed-Size: 74945
Maintainer: MySQL Workbench team <workbench@sun.com>
Architecture: i386
Source: mysql-workbench
Version: 5.2.44-1ubu1204
Replaces: mysql-workbench-oss
Depends: libatkmm-1.6-1 (>= 2.22.1), libc6 (>= 2.15), libcairo2 (>= 1.8.0), libctemplate0, libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0), libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1, libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8), libglibmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 2.32.0), libgnome-keyring0 (>= 2.22.2), libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0), libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 1:2.24.0), liblua5.1-0, libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.13-1), libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.18.0), libpangomm-1.4-1 (>= 2.27.1), libpcre3 (>= 8.10), libpython2.7 (>= 2.7), libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.0.2), libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.5.9), libstdc++6 (>= 4.6), libuuid1 (>= 2.16), libx11-6, libxml2 (>= 2.7.4), libzip2 (>= 0.10), python-paramiko, python-pexpect, mysql-client, python-pysqlite2
Suggests: gnome-keyring
...
```

**Edit 3**

I see that when trying to install some other software via apt-get, they all complain about mysql-workbench:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-workbench-gpl:i386 : Depends: libatkmm-1.6-1:i386 (>= 2.22.1) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libctemplate0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libglibmm-2.4-1c2a:i386 (>= 2.32.0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a:i386 (>= 1:2.24.0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: liblua5.1-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libpangomm-1.4-1:i386 (>= 2.27.1) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libpython2.7:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:i386 (>= 2.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libzip2:i386 (>= 0.10) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: python-paramiko:i386 but it is not installable
                            Depends: python-pexpect:i386 but it is not installable
                            Depends: mysql-client:i386
                            Depends: python-pysqlite2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
```

Comment: I don't see a problem. Upgrading will keep (hopefully, but that's another problem) backward-compatibility, so Python 3 will support Python 2.7 as well. What's the concern?

Comment: The concern is that some modules installed for python 2.7 won't work for python3. Or paths, settings... I don't know, I'm just conservative in the python area since have half of my thesis depends on it and so I try to avoid  surprises.

Comment: That's another thing then. If you *need* (*need* to be interpreted as "must have") Python 2.7 for whatever reason obviously you shouldn't remove it, there's no question about it. You may hold Python 2.7 in your `apt` settings in order to be able to upgrade other packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not safe to accept the removal of python2.7 because [uninstalling python2.7 will also remove a lot of other packages that you need](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55467/removed-python-from-my-install-how-do-i-get-it-back). The safe way to accomplish what you are trying to do in Ubuntu 12.04 is to install the version of MySQL Workbench from the default Ubuntu repositories.

In order to do this, you need to repair your package catalog. [Fixing software center catalog](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30993/fixing-software-center-catalog) says to open the terminal and run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-workbench*  
sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get install -f
```

Unlike, python2.7, you can safely remove mysql-workbench without breaking anything else, and reinstall mysql-workbench later after your package catalog has been repaired. The `sudo apt-get install -f` command will only be executed if the `sudo dpkg --configure -a` command succeeds.

Reviewing the packages that you have installed since you installed Ubuntu, the package that stands out is RStudio. There is an official RStudio .deb package [here](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/) for Ubuntu 12.04, however you compiled RStudio from its source code because you couldn't install it from the .deb file. This is probably where you are getting your broken package catalog problem from. I suggest that you remove RStudio: [If I build a package from source how can I uninstall or remove it completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely), repair your package catalog, install MySQL Workbench from the Ubuntu Software Center, and then the only problem left to solve will be how to reinstall RStudio without breaking anything else.

Comment: I don't see any PPA either my sources.list or sources.lists.d/ files

Comment: May I ask why you state that the "to be removed" packages are needed? Genuine question, AFAIK explicilty installed packages, aside from edge cases, won't be removed unless explicitly asked to be so

Comment: @karel: after `gksudo software-center` a pop up warns me: Items cannot be installed or removed until the package catalog is repaired. Do you want to repair it now? I said yes. "Failed to remove essential system package" ("python-minimal cannot be removed")

Comment: Same result after successful `sudo apt-get update`. If I click cancel it lets me get into the Software Center anyway.

Comment: dpkg configure does not succeed: 

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-workbench-gpl:i386: depends on libatkmm-1.6-1 (>= 2.22.1)...libpython2.7 (>= 2.7), etc

Comment: I'll edit the question with the results

Comment: It says they are not installed, and yet it warns me about the unmet dependencies.

Comment: Weird, I would not remeber having installed it from the tar.gz. My ubuntu is one week old and the only non-apt installations have been cmake, rstudio... latex and I think that's all

Comment: But I did an `apt-get remove apache2` and I have the feeling it messed up something.

Comment: Weird, I thought the unmet dependencies might have been caused by installing RStudio, although I know there is an official RStudio .deb package [here](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/) for Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Yes, but I had to compile it from the sources since I couldn't install from .deb

Comment: Update: what I think I did 1) tried to install the 0.99 version from .deb. 2) tried to compile it. 3) succeeded in installing 0.98 from .deb apt-get remove studio complains about mysql workbench. dpkg -r rstudio does not find the package.

Comment: Final: This worked! `sudo gdebi mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1ubu1204-amd64.deb` and then `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get install -f ` does nothing since everything seems back to normal.