# Preventing deadly/fatal commands from being run

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, security, blacklist

After recently reading the article "[8 Deadly Commands You Should Never Run on Linux](http://www.howtogeek.com/125157/8-deadly-commands-you-should-never-run-on-linux/)", I've planned on somehow blocking/preventing/changing certain commands. I'm not worried that someone else will run destructive commands on my PC. I'm worried that I may be the culprit behind the accident.

I am worried about the commands listed below.

```
wget http://example.com/something -O – | sh –
```

- I've run this line when I was copying & pasting commands from a
  guide. Had I noticed `sh -`, I'd have only run that after checking
  out the archive contents.

```
rm -rf /
```

- I accidentally hit the 'Enter' key a lot...

I want to prevent making these mistakes in the future. Is there a command/configuration file that can ensure I don't commit these mistakes? I do not want to be able to run the commands above even with sudo/root permissions. It it okay if the solution can be reversed.

Resources that will help me learn more about Ubuntu (excluding common Ubuntu Wiki/Help/etc. links) would be **greatly appreciated**!

Data loss isn't my main concern. I want to make the terminal a little safer for myself ('newb-proofed' if you will). This would be helpful to me as I've got lot's to learn. I've started school again, & I can't be spending too much of my time resolving problems/error (as interesting as it is).

**Edit**:

Is it possible to require specific commands to ask for confirmation? If I wanted to set specific commands to require a special password, can it be done?

Comment: *nix does not prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot. On a properly configured Ubuntu system, however, `sudo rm -rf /` will fail without adding `--no-preserve-root` to the end. For these specific examples, I think a bashrc alias could be of use.

Comment: There are way more destructive  commands than you have seen in that article.  Your  best security is knowing what you type,  not just blacklisting everything

Comment: Just FYI, some of the alledgedly "dangerous commands" in that article are nonsense. For instance, `mv ~ /dev/null` will not "move your home directory to a black hole". Rather, it will fail because you can't move a directoty to a file. Even if you tried to move a file (instead of a directory) in this way, you wouldn't move the file to a black hole, but rather overwrite your `/dev/null` device (see [my answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/435892/223688) for more details).

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa Thanks for the comment. I wasn't worried about any cmds other than listed above in my post. I appreciate the knowledge you've shared though =)! Pointing out the 'fairy tale facts'  of someone's source is fantastic of you to do. (warning: this comment contains no sarcasm.)

Comment: Another interesting read: http://askubuntu.com/questions/430702/remove-a-terminal-command

Comment: Step 1: [don't copy and paste code](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/05/26/why-you-cant-trust-things-you-cut-and-paste-from-web-pages/) from a website, ever.

Comment: I've edited my post, adding two additional questions at the end.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As I've said in the comments, *knowing what you type is the best security*.

Here's an example , that has been used in a [related question](https://askubuntu.com/a/649244/295286)

```
`base64 --decode <<< "cHJpbnRmICclcycgICdIZWxsbyBXb3JsZCcK"`
```

( and for completeness, you can use `-d` flag instead of `--decode`. Someone who tried editing my answer said `-d` is invalid, however it's very much valid, specified [in the manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/base64.1.html))

Do you know what this does ? It's a disguised `printf '%s'  'Hello World'`. Harmless , right? What if this was `rm -rf /` ? Blacklisting won't save you when something is disguised. Can you see this command put on a legitimate forum by a malicious user ? Because that does happen. And it doesn't have to be exactly that command - if you are new user and have no idea what you're doing, a malicious user could tell you [remove python](https://askubuntu.com/q/796598/295286) or some other key package, and that would fix whatever issue that has brought you to their blog or forum.

But sure, you could blacklist something via global function (because functions take precedence over commands or aliases) in `/etc/bash.bashrc` like this:

```
function rm{

if [ "$1" = "-rf" ] && [ "$2" = "/" ]
then
    echo "This command is bad juju"
else
    rm "$@"
fi


}
```

This is just an example. And very redundant one - `rm -rf /` on Ubuntu by default requires confirmation.

This is also not bulletproof. What if I as attacker use a different shell ? Your `bashrc` magic won't have power in `dash` shell , which comes with Ubuntu also by default

Also, are you going to write function to blacklist each and every single malicious command ?

---

Additional note: copying what appears to be "harmless" command can also be dangerous. See [How can I protect myself from this kind of clipboard abuse?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39118/121824) and Stephane Chazelas' answer on the subject.

Comment: And `cd / && rm -rf *` does not :P

Comment: Do not cp somefilename /dev/sda, any data loss.

Comment: Agree. From top of my head, any redirection to ` /dev/sdx` ( like > or >> ) is enough to destroy your data, no need to bother blocking commands, it's not worth the effort. Looping through disk devices in dev and strafing beginning and end parts with small amounts of bytes is enough to corrupt MBR or GPT partitions.