# Can't Install or remove anything on Ubuntu 16.04 because py3clean and py3compile not found

Tags: package-management, dpkg, python3

I am unable to install or upgrade anything on Ubuntu 16.04.I am missing package python3-software-properties and can't install it anyhow . I have posted the various tracebacks. I tried installing these packages and got these errors.

```
sarfraz@sarfraz:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
language-selector-common language-selector-gnome python3-distupgrade           
python3-software-properties software-properties-common software-  properties-gtk
Recommended packages:
unattended-upgrades
The following packages will be upgraded:language-selector-common
language-selector-gnome python3-distupgrade python3-software-
properties software-properties-common software-properties-gtk
6 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 30 not     upgraded.
 141 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 2,083 kB/2,496 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64     dpkg amd64 1.18.4ubuntu1.1 [2,083 kB]
Fetched 2,083 kB in 3s (617 kB/s) 
(Reading database ... 220260 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../language-selector-gnome_0.165.4_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-gnome.prerm: 6:         /var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-gnome.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit    status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean:  not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/language-selector-gnome_0.165.4_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-gnome.postinst: 6:     /var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-gnome.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../dpkg_1.18.4ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dpkg (1.18.4ubuntu1.1) over (1.18.4ubuntu1.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/language-selector-gnome_0.165.4_all.deb
```

```
sarfraz@sarfraz:~$ sudo apt-get install python3-minimal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-minimal is already the newest version (3.5.1-3).
The following additional packages will be installed:
language-selector-common language-selector-gnome python3-distupgrade    
python3-software-properties software-properties-common software- properties-gtk
Recommended packages:
  unattended-upgrades
The following packages will be upgraded:
  language-selector-common language-selector-gnome python3-distupgrade  python3-software-properties software-properties-common software- properties-gtk
6 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.
141 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/413 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 220260 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../language-selector-gnome_0.165.4_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-gnome.prerm: 6:         /var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-gnome.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/language-    selector-gnome_0.165.4_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-gnome.postinst: 6:     /var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-gnome.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit     status 127
Preparing to unpack .../language-selector-common_0.165.4_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-common.prerm: 21:     /var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-common.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit     status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 21: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/language-    selector-common_0.165.4_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-common.postinst: 23:    /var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-common.postinst: py3compile: not   found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/language-selector-gnome_0.165.4_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/language-selector-common_0.165.4_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
sarfraz@sarfraz:~$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.1).
openssl is already the newest version (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.1).
The following additional packages will be installed:
  language-selector-common language-selector-gnome python3-distupgrade     python3-software-properties software-properties-common software-    properties-gtk
Recommended packages:
  unattended-upgrades
The following packages will be upgraded:
  language-selector-common language-selector-gnome python3-distupgrade     python3-software-properties software-properties-common software-  properties-gtk
6 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.
141 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/413 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
 (Reading database ... 220260 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../language-selector-gnome_0.165.4_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-gnome.prerm: 6:     /var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-gnome.prerm: py3clean: not found
 dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/language-    selector-gnome_0.165.4_all.deb (--unpack):
subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-gnome.postinst: 6:     /var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-gnome.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../language-selector-common_0.165.4_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-common.prerm: 21:     /var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-common.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
 /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 21: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/language-selector-common_0.165.4_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-common.postinst: 23:     /var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-common.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit     status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/language-selector-gnome_0.165.4_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/language-selector-common_0.165.4_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
sarfraz@sarfraz:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystic-mirage/pycharm/ubuntu xenial InRelease  
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package python3-software-properties needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

```
sarfraz@sarfraz:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-software-properties
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package python3-software-properties needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

```
sarfraz@sarfraz:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-software-properties
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package python3-software-properties needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

```
sarfraz@sarfraz:~$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package python3-software-properties needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

```
sarfraz@sarfraz:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-software-properties
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package python3-software-properties needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

```
sarfraz@sarfraz:~$ sudo dpkg -i Downloads/python3-software-properties_0.92.36_all.deb 
(Reading database ... 220260 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-software-properties_0.92.36_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-software-properties.prerm: 6:     /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-software-properties.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive Downloads/python3-software-    properties_0.92.36_all.deb (--install):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-software-properties.postinst: 6:      /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-software-properties.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 Downloads/python3-software-properties_0.92.36_all.deb
sarfraz@sarfraz:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystic-mirage/pycharm/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

```
sarfraz@sarfraz:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package python3-software-properties needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I deleted package 'python3' on Ubuntu and I have lost dashboard, terminal and Unity. Help me to restore my data please](http://askubuntu.com/questions/810854/i-deleted-package-python3-on-ubuntu-and-i-have-lost-dashboard-terminal-and-un)

Comment: For future reference, please don't delete Python 3 ever again. It is critical to your system.

Comment: It is not duplicate. A different problem. I am able to access everything like desktop etc. But can't install anything

Comment: @edwinksl I don't see any reference that he removed python. I have faced this issue as well after updating alternatives to make python3.6 default over python3.7

Comment: Same question appeared today: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159213/gdebi-corrupted-how-to-fix I'm wondering how you solved this problem...

Answer (score 4):

Try running the following command:

```
apt-get  -f install
```

to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.

Try also: `dpkg --configure -a`.

---

If above won't help, try reinstalling your core Python installation as `py3compile` file is part of `python3-minimal` package, so if you still got the problem, try reinstalling that package. If you can't reinstall using `apt-get`, try to [download `.pkg` file from kernel.org](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/) and install manually (python3-minimal*). E.g.

```
dpkg -i python3-minimal_*.deb
```

Also make sure that `py3compile` is accessible based on your current `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but I was able to resolve my broken Python3 system installation with `sudo apt install python3-minimal python3 --reinstall`

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

First I installed python3-all to reinstall Python and anything else missing as per this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/810914/640078

```
sudo apt install python3-all
```

This installed most of the stuff, but with a couple of issues; I proceeded as follows:

I did `sudo apt -f install`, and got several errors like this:

```
Need to get 0 B/183 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package python3-yaml (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
.
.
.
.
dpkg: error processing package update-notifier (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-yaml
 netplan.io
 ubuntu-advantage-tools
 update-manager
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
 update-notifier
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I installed python3-yaml first, then ubuntu-advantage-tools:

```
sudo apt install python3-yaml
sudo apt install ubuntu-advantage-tools
```

I then did `sudo apt install -f`  and `sudo apt autoremove` and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Best answer is to reinstall.
But i managed to fix this--

Install python on any other machine i.e VPS
apt install python python3 python-all python-minimal python3-minimal

Once you have pythone installed on your VPS or another PC.

cd /var/lib
zip -r fix.zip dpkg

Now copy this file(from VPS download) to your system at /var/lib
unzip fiz.zip
Press A to overwrite ALL

Now on your machine
apt install python3-all python3-minimal --reinstall
apt autoremove

FIXED