# Python3.5 deleted from /usr/bin/py* in 16.04

Tags: python3

I upgraded to 16.04 three weeks back. In my `/usr/bin` I have all python versions from 2.7 to 3.5. By default `/usr/bin/python` pointed to python2.7. I tried to make it point to python3.5.

I went through some tech site instructions and ended up creating a softlink `/usr/bin/python3.5 -> /usr/local/bin/python` but `/usr/local/bin/python` didn't exist. In an attempt to clean up the broken `/usr/bin/python3.5` link, I also ended up deleting the `/usr/bin/python3.5` executable. I tried to upgrade python or my distribution but I am getting errors.

How can I fix this? I can't open gnome-terminal.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

Do not use upgrade follow the instructions here [I deleted package 'python3' on Ubuntu and I have lost dashboard, terminal and Unity. Help me to restore my data please](https://askubuntu.com/questions/810854/i-deleted-package-python3-on-ubuntu-and-i-have-lost-dashboard-terminal-and-un)

In future use update-alternatives instead of creating symlinks manually https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux