# Purged python3 , terminal , software center and some packages are missing

Tags: package-management, python, software-center, python3, purge

I was trying to remove python3 and reinstall it, but didn't had an idea about purge, so accidentally purged it. Now terminal, software center, and important library are missing.

I am aware of the solution:

[Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications)

and

[I deleted package 'python3' on Ubuntu and I have lost dashboard, terminal and Unity. Help me to restore my data please](https://askubuntu.com/questions/810854/i-deleted-package-python3-on-ubuntu-and-i-have-lost-dashboard-terminal-and-un?noredirect=1&lq=1)

but none of them seem to work. Installing most packages require python3 dependency which is not met and I am prompted to execute `apt-get -f install`
for which i get
[image: image of error in Xterm]

I am using Xterm as substitute of terminal.

Please help to restore.

Comment: Please do not take screenshot of running terminal, instead copy the output and paste them here using `code` block.

Comment: You're using Ubuntu 16.04, yes?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3.5-minimal`

Comment: @Emmet sorry, newbie

Comment: @wjandrea not working, dependency issues

Comment: @Prakhar Please [edit] to add the output. Also switch that screenshot for text while you're there please.