# Python3 deinstallation killed OS

Tags: boot, laptop, python3

So I was trying to get anaconda python to work with vscode. So I decided to remove python3 and see if the editor asks me if I want another interpreter. I ran `sudo apt remove python3` and saw that many packages will be removed, but due to me beeing not the experienced linux user I couldn't figure out if they were important. Well now after a reboot I can only decrypt my harddrive but I can't login, the screen is black. Any ideas on how to get the os back up? Or at least a way to get my files before reinstalling the whole os?

Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: You haven't provided OS/release details, however many Ubuntu tools rely on `python` (`python3` for some releases) so if removed, they won't work and that should have been  be expected.  Please start with your OS/release.

Comment: Can you boot into recovery mode by pressing shift when the maker's logo appears? If yes, check these logs `/var/log/apt/term.log` and `/var/log/apt/history.log` and reinstall what was removed doing a full update and upgrade, if you can. If your system is purged of packages like `libc6` etc, you have to do a clean install. Possible duplicate https://askubuntu.com/questions/810854/

Comment: @guiverc I added it. 19.09 or 19.10.

Comment: There is no 19.09.

Comment: And the latest would be 20.04  ;-)

Comment: @kortewegdevries the libc6 seems not to be removed. Should I reinstall everything one by one, or would you recommend me to do it like the other question suggests?

Comment: Can you log into some sort of terminal and can use `apt-get` or `dpkg`?

Comment: @Rinzwind Yeah I just stumbled over it.

Comment: @kortewegdevries I opend in recovery mode. But there are issues if I want to run any apt get install or update.

Comment: Then follow Rinzwind's suggestion.

Comment: @kortewegdevries ok I will try it a final time with Lan plugged in and if it doesn't work I will do that.

Comment: @kortewegdevries I've got it. I plugged in the Ethernet cable 2x times and after the second time I could follow the post. Thx problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas on how to get the os back up? Or at least a way to get my files before reinstalling the whole os?

Please re-install the OS. You can make backups from the live session and during setup you can also mount **without formatting** the partitions that hold your data. The installer will only overwrite system related files when partitions are mounted. Make sure to use the same mount point names for the different partitions.

Another method could be to remove the disk from the system and install a new OS on a brand new disk and then mount your old one. That would allow you to copy all your files to the new system.

Comment: Yes thats a good idea, should have had the same, could I even install the new version 20.04 or could there be an issue with the file management.

Comment: I have 20.04 running since januari with no issues.,

Comment: So I think I go with your salution, just downloaded Ubuntu 20.04.