# deleted python3 and solutions don't work (apt-get maybe the problem?)

Tags: apt, python

I know it was really silly command but I deleted python3…
I read almost all of the solution you guys gave but it doesn’t work.

‘

First of all, I tried some solutions suggested in
[Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/q/384033/402539)
[I deleted package 'python3' on Ubuntu and I have lost dashboard, terminal and Unity. Help me to restore my data please](https://askubuntu.com/q/810854/402539)

But first of all, in my Ubuntu, sudo apt-get update doesn’t work. I tried to change the source file but it doesn’t work.
Also I checked the nameserver set in /etc/resolv.conf.
[error code…ahah](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT6SB.jpg)

Main point is I tried every command suggested in those links and they didn’t work. I think remove python3 and apt-get doesn’t work at all, including apt-get update.

Can anyone give me a help?

Comment: How did you removed python3

Comment: `apt-get` and like tools need python3 working before they can work.  That is expected, you need to use base commands like `wget` and `dpkg` to reinstall... ie. not the front-end tools (that need python3) that make it easier to do things...  You didn't provide release details; but if you install `python3-minimal` it's usually pretty easy to get most things working/fixed using higher-level tools  (*adjust for your unstated release/product*)

Comment: The main issue is that Python3 is the default version, hence you have probably wrecked your system. Any other solutions that might work should be added to the above Q&A, which covers the exact same topic.

Comment: @guiverc Ah I didn’t know apt-get is also python3 based. I tried every command in https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications and it didn’t work

Comment: @guiverc I’ll try python3-minimal thanks!

Comment: @ArturMeinild I don’t think is exact same question, cuz apt-get doesn’t work at all in my Ubuntu. I’ve tried every command suggested in that link

Comment: You misunderstand. It's the same question, but maybe there isn't a suitable answer. This can be redeemed, however.

Comment: If you're using a Ubuntu Core product (eg. Ubuntu Core 20 or another *year* format product), there is no `apt`, `apt-get`, or `dpkg` like commands as they are *snap* package only products; thus differ to the common *year.month* format products of Ubuntu.  Adding python3 won't change that.